# wordpress plugin that replaces the HTML/PHP code of page.php or the home page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, replace, removechild

For quite a while I am stacked with the above issue. I have done (I believe) a thorough research on the topic and tried to implement what I found, but unfortunately without any luck.
I have been working on a content-slider plugin (which now works as tandalone jquery), but in order to be able to make it as a wordpress plugin I need to add and remove various code-components from the original page.php file (or other files if the user choose a different template). I thought the best way to do this would be to "clear" the code in the existing template whatever it is and add my own after that.

I am not too familiar with php but tried to achieve this with a function which I hoped will do what I need.

In the php file of my plugin I added a function:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'remove_contents');

function remove_contents(){
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html(home_url());

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$featuredde1 = $dom->getElementById('main-content');
foreach ($featuredde1 as $node) {
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

I hoped this function would remove the "main-content" div with all it's contents and leave empty space, but what happened instead is I received tons of error messages.

Again I am not so experienced with php, but could anybody advice how I might could solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is inside of your #main-content area entirely, but if your target is the content part of a post or page you can create a filter on `the_content` in your Wordress Plugin.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: Thanks for replying Matt. This is actually what I tried at the beginning but I would like to remove everything not just the contents but their parent divs. I need this as I am planning to use <ul> and not <div> all trough. Basically I would like to wipe out the code from the actual template selected for the home page and insert mine instead.